# My keyboard shorcuts won't save (VS code)

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, text, keyboard-shortcuts

I downloaded the last version of VS code, and since I use a Dvorak layout for typing, I changed the position of the keys of some shorcuts that come handy. It works, but every time I restart my PC, VS code don't save my changes, so I have to re-configure my shorcuts over and over, which is very annoying.

Does anyone know what may be happenging and how can I fix it?

Comment: vscode stores the settings in a keybinding.json file in your library. You can get the path on click on https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0URi.png. When you exist vscode make sure the file is still there. If not, it might be permissions issues. If it keeps happening, maybe you should create an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on settings sync by clicking the gear icon > then sign in to sync settings and > then you can use your Microsoft or Github account